# How to retrieve elements using hash values in STL hash containers?

Tags: c++, hash, stl

I am using unordered set to store strings. Here it is possible to have different strings to have same hash value, so I have to add to linked list for that hash value. Is this is supported in C++ stl unordered_set.

```
std::unordered_set<std::string, hashFunction> m_Dictionary;
```

I inserted "world: which has hash value 4 and another word "HellO" which has hash value 4 so both should go to the dictionary. How we can achieve this.

Another requirement is that I want to search by string, if string present in dictionary it should return true.

Also I want to search by hash value i.e., 4 then I should get output as "world" and "HellO".

Is this can be achieved by unordered_set or unordered_map. I want to use STL hash containers.

Basically I want to search using strings and with hash value. If hash value has multiple strings then we have to print all strings with that hash value. I am looking for sample code how we can achieve this.

I am aware that we can do this with out using STL hash containers, I am wondering is this possible with STL hash containers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `std::unordered_multiset`? Your question is not very clear, to be honest.

Comment: You do not need to worry about strings hashing to the same values - unordered_set takes this possibility into account, as must all hash-table implementations.

Comment: @SergeyA basically I want to search using strings and with hash value. If hash value has multiple strings then we have to print all strings with that hash value. I am looking for sample code how we can achieve this. I reformatted my question. Thanks

Comment: Those are two separate questions. First is 'how do we put strings which have the same hash value into unordered_set'. Answer is - don't worry about it, set takes care of that. Second question is: how do we search by hash value in `std::unordered_set`. The answer is 'you don't', there is no such API.

Comment: Standard hash containers do not support searching by hash value. However if you have a key, you can get the bucket of that key. All other elements with the same *or equivalent* hash reside in that bucket.

Comment: afaik the second template parameter is not the hash function

Answer (score 0):

The hash container already supports objects that have the same hash. Basically, they are all pushed into a sublist and linearly searched through, so it is more expensive if your hash is poor. You can't search by hash value in the stl.

If you really need to use hash values then you will need to put a wrapper round an unordered_multimap indexed by integer, where your wrapper has hashed to the key, which will store multiple values at the same key. You can use equal_range() to return a pair of iterators covering the common key.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample code how we can write wrapper idea you suggested. I am new to advance STL Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to do the hashing yourself? If not, then the unordered_map already handles the issue.